# R readHTMLTable function not working

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I have the following code written in R in which I would like to obtain some names from [this particular webpage](http://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic-passengers-crew-lived/country-17/england.html).

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
x <- getURL("http://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic-passengers-crew-lived/country-17/england.html")
x_2 <- htmlParse(x)
x_3 <- readHTMLTable(x_2)
```

However, whenever I look at the contents of x_3, I get the following...

```
x_3
named list()
```

It seems as though the readHTMLTable function is not able to obtain the tables. Can anyone help me obtain the names of the passengers from this web page without having to copy and paste? Much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to extract the table element first before you can use readHTMLTable().  Use XPath - something like `tableVar <- xpathApply(x_2, "//table[@id='manifest']")`. Then you should be able to do `x_3 <- readHTMLTable(tableVar)`

Comment: (I'm having firewall issues ATM so I can't test this, by the way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

base <- "http://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic-passengers-crew-lived/country-17/england.html"

# I use the older rvest package...`html` might be `read_html` now.Link to git repo below:
# https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/7d65d84e013b1bb3827ae0a2e05ddaed4875c112/R/parse.R
data_df <- (html(base) %>% html_table)[[1]]

knitr::kable(summary(data_df))

    |   |    Name         |    Age          | Class/Dept      |   Ticket        |   Joined        |    Job          |Boat [Body]      |             |
    |:--|:----------------|:----------------|:----------------|:----------------|:----------------|:----------------|:----------------|:------------|
    |   |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Length:1190      |Mode:logical |
    |   |Class :character |Class :character |Class :character |Class :character |Class :character |Class :character |Class :character |NA's:1190    |
    |   |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |Mode  :character |NA           |
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. Works nicely!

Comment: glad to hear it @ACE